# Unchecked conversion warning with generic type in IntelliJ

Tags: java, generics

My IDE (IntelliJ) warns me about an unchecked conversion:

> Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found 'com.company.Main.Cat', required 'T'

Nevertheless my code works as expected. Is there something I can do to prevent this warning or does my code have a "design" flaw?

The following MCVE reproduces the warning in `public Cat copy()` for `Cat`.

```
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Cat cat = new Cat( "Mimi" );
      Cat copyCat = cat.copy();
   }

   public static class Cat extends Animal
   {
      public String name;

      public Cat( final String name )
      {
         this.name = name;
      }

      @Override
      public Cat copy() // Unchecked conversion warning
      {
         return new Cat( this.name );
      }

   }

   public abstract static class Animal
   {
      abstract < T extends Animal > T copy();
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Animal.copy` method is generic, suggesting that the caller can specify the type of animal they want... but your implementation *isn't* generic.

So for example, here's a slightly augmented and changed version of your code - note the change to the `main` method, which uses just `Animal` as the variable type, but specifies a type argument for the `copy` method:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal cat = new Cat("Mimi");
        Dog copyCat = cat.<Dog>copy();
    }

    public static class Cat extends Animal {
        public String name;

        public Cat(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public Cat copy() {
            return new Cat(this.name);
        }

    }

    public abstract static class Dog extends Animal {
    }

    public abstract static class Animal {
        abstract <T extends Animal> T copy();
    }
}
```

The `main` method compiles without warning - it's fine.

But at execution time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Test$Cat cannot be cast to Test$Dog
        at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

So yes, your code has a design flaw, and only works as expected in the use case you started with. You almost certainly don't want to make the method generic. You could either make the *class* generic, or just declare the abstract `copy` method as returning `Animal`:

```java
public abstract static class Animal {
    abstract Animal copy();
}
```

Now that would allow `Dog.copy()` to be declared to return `Cat` of course... but it's at least simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic `copy()` method to work the way you expect it, I'd change the two classes like that:

```
public abstract static class Animal<T extends Animal> {
   abstract T copy();
}

public static class Cat extends Animal<Cat> {
    public String name;

    public Cat(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Cat copy() {
        return new Cat(this.name);
    }
}
```

This way, the `Animal` class can have generic methods, and the subclasses like `Cat`, knowing what type to insert for the type variable `T`, specify concrete classes.

Now, `Animal.copy()` is known to return an `Animal` (exactly: some type `T` that extends `Animal`), and `Cat.copy()` a `Cat`, exactly what we expect.

### On method generics

One remark on generic type parameters to methods, as in your version of the `Animal.copy()` method. If you don't have a method argument with that variable type, it's an error in 99% of cases.

A method like

```
    public <T extends Animal> T copy(T originalAnimal) { ... }
```

can be okay. The compile-time type of the argument then tells the compiler what to expect as result, and it's possible (e.g. using `clone()`) to implement a method that returns an instance of the same class that it got as its argument.

But with a method like

```
    public <T extends Animal> T copy() { ... }
```

it's already hard for the compiler to determine the `T` type (sometimes it's possible from the variable where you assign the value into, or you can supply the `<Cat>` type infix).

But even more, you don't know the `T` type at runtime, and don't have any info available in your method implementation whether `T` is somehow bound to `Cat`, `Dog` or whatever. So you can't implement a method that follows this signature.

Rule of thumb: prefer generic type parameters to classes over those to methods.

Comment: Thanks for your additional clarification, i ended up implementing generic types to classes as you proposed. Before I struggled to understand the issues to determine the type of T for generic methods.